# .NET Core Dependency Injection; Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a service and a model to get the parameter for its constructor and then the controller uses that service. I also use dependency injection and i can't quite point as to how declare the service, because it requires a parameter.
I have already looked into another similar questions, but none of the answers seem to work for me. The error i get is: "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'authentication.Services.RDStationServices.RDStationService'.

The code connected to this matter:

```
public class RDStationService : IRDStationService
{
public RDStationService(string server)
    {
        _endPoint = server;
        _client = new RestClient
        {
            BaseUrl = new Uri(_endPoint)
        };
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class RDStationOptions
{
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

Enviroment variable:

```
"RDStationOptions": {
"Url": "https://www.rdstation.com.br/api/1.3/"}
```

Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var configOptionsRDStation = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(RDStationOptions));
        var _rdStationInstance = new RDStationService(configOptionsRDStation[nameof(RDStationOptions.Url)]);
        services.AddSingleton(_rdStationInstance);
}
```

This configuration inside the *ConfigureServices* is my latest attempt of informing the string to the constructer, but i keep getting the same error.
Any suggestions, please?

Comment: which DI library are you using?

Comment: Show your service DI registration, I'm sure you do not specify string value in constructor

Comment: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use ASP.NET Core I assume your `Configuration` instance is type of `IConfiguration`. This should work for you:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{       
    var configOptionsRDStation = Configuration.GetSection("RDStationOptions : Url");
    var _rdStationInstance = new RDStationService(configOptionsRDStation.Value);
    services.AddSingleton(_rdStationInstance);
}
```

If you want to use `IOptions`:

```
services.Configure<RDStationOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("RDStationOptions"));
services.AddOptions()
```

Comment: Had to work with an error about empty variable, but now it's finally working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works as intended. I feel that your error is being caused by other code. Maybe post the rest of your configuration.

An example of somewhere I would expect this to happen:

```
services.AddSingleton(_rdStationInstance);

// Will NOT work, will created a scoped RDStationService and try to resolve string
services.AddScoped<IRDStationService, RDStationService>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Options.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I think it will be better idea

Comment: Don't just post a link, explain and say what's described there.